# How can I organize controls on a form relative to one another and the form itself?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, controls

I have a child form in a MDI Windows Forms application. It has two controls: a ComboBox and a TreeView, with the last one under the first one. Both controls have the same width. How can I set up them and form properties to achieve the following:

1. When changing the size of the form, a width of both controls must be equal to the width of the form.
2. The height of the TreeView must be changing to fill all free space of the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do like this:

1. In the forms designer, layout the controls like you want them to look
2. Select the ComboBox, and set the [`Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) property to Top, Left and Right
3. Select the TreeView and set the `Anchor` property to Top, Left, Right, and Bottom

Comment: Thank you. It works almost properly - there is a problem when resizing form through the bottom of the form. Perhaps, it's because of wrong Z-order parameters. How can I repair that?

Comment: @Peter17: what kind of problem is it?

Comment: When I am resizing the form to the down, the treeView is not resizing but just moving down.

Comment: @Peter17: sounds as if you have not assigned `Top` in the `Anchor` property. The `TreeView` should be ancored in all four directions.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: I was wondering. When I expand treeview element and some nodes are outside the visible area. And, despite that Autoscroll property of the form is true, the scroll bar doesn't appear. Is there any way to establish proper autoscroll in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you would need to dock your controls. Play with the **[Dock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx)** property of your both controls to find the "docking" which suits your requirements.

Here is an example which demonstrates a *Combobox* with `Dock=Top` and *TreeView* with `Dock=Fill`:

[image]

If you resize the form, the *Combobox* width and *TreeView* width/height will be resized accordingly, which suits your specific requirements.

Comment: +1 - it's also worth mentioning that the docking layout is performed bottom-up, so the `ComboBox` must be "below" the `TreeView` in the Z-Order.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that forms without a bit of padding look awkward and unprofessional to the user. I'm not sure whether there is any guideline that dictates this.

Comment: @Vilx: there are a lot of ways to achieve padding (anchoring is not the only way to do that), setting nice borders, setting fonts, labelled panels, etc. But that definitely will be out of the scope of that specific technical question.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk. How can I change Z-Order? Because it seems that it works not completely correctly now.

Comment: @Peter17: first select the `TreeView`, right-click and select "Send to Back". Then do the same with the `ComboBox`. That way the `ComboBox` will be located below the `TreeView` in the Z-Order. That means that when docking layout is performed, first the `ComboBox` will be docked to the top, then the `TreeView` will take whatever space is left over.

Answer (score 1):

This is done by the `Anchor` property. Set it properly on all controls (combobox, treeview and usercontrol) and it will stretch however way you like.

The `Dock` property is similar, but it also affects location and kinda "glues" the control to its place even in the form designer.